# SPF Setup - Sending from VPS and Google Apps

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, vps, g-suite, spf

In follow up to [my question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/112663/550-invalid-helo-ehlo-must-contain-a-fqdn-or-ipv6), how on earth do I setup a SPF record?!?

I understand that I have to add a TXT record to my DNS entries but what to put in that TXT entry is what's confusing me...

I have a Windows 2008 VPS with two IPs - `x.x.x.10` & `x.x.x.20`

I have two RDNS records for `x.x.x.10` => `bob.charlino.com` & `x.x.x.20` => `simon.charlino.com`

I have a web application setup on the server `vallenous.com` (note: different from the rDNS entries)

`vallenous.com` is setup to use google apps for email BUT I do wish to send some emails from the web application itself through the local SMTP server (IIS6 SMTP) on my VPS.

In response to the answers to my previous question, I've set the FQDN in my smtp virtual server to equal `bob.charlino.com` because when you send an email through the `vallenous.com` web applicaiton it seems to come from `x.x.x.10`.

Was this the correct thing to do? I noticed when I did this google mail wasn't giving it a soft fail anymore...

Secondly, how on earth do I setup the SPF record? I've done some googling but it all just confuses me. I need to setup it for google apps (which is [outlined here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33786)) but I also need to set it up so I can send from my VPS.

And yes, I've seen a couple of SPF [generater](http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html) [thingies](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/) but they aren't really clearing up any confusion... just adding to it really.

Comment: A down vote without a comment... what gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest that you need the following in your TXT record:

`"v=spf1 mx ip4:x.x.x.10 include:aspmx.googlemail.com ~all"`

This was generated by the first SPF [generator](http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html) you linked to.

It states that your domain is using SPF v1.

The `mx` keyboard states that any server listed in a DNS MX record as a mail server is allowed to send mail from this domain.

The `ipv4:` bit states that the given IPv4 address is allowed to send mail from this domain.

The `include:` part states that any server allowed to send mail for the aspmx.googlemail.com domain is also allowed to send for your domain - this bit lets google apps email work.  If google add/change which servers they use, they will change their SPF record for their aspmx.googlemail.com domain (and hence your domain will carrying on working without needed to be changed any time google make a change...)

The `~all` part states that the previous parts should be all the allowed mail servers.  Any other server sending email claiming to be from this domain is *probably* in error - accept the email but you might want to check it more thoroughly for spam,etc.

If you use `-all` instead of `~all`, it states that any other server sending email claiming to be from this domain is *definitely* in error - don't accept the email (or accept and delete it).  Google recommend you don't use this setting as it can be a bit over-vealous and lead to mail being lost.

Comment: Brilliant... that seems like a great run down, cleared up most of my confusion. So in the example that @mat gave, the `a` and `ptr` are just like the `mx` part? Allowing any of the `a` or `ptr` dns records are allowed to send?

Comment: The `a` part states that mail is allowed to come from the server "vallenous.com" (i.e. from the IP address in the "A" record for vallenous.com.  The `ptr` part states mail is allowed to come from *any* IP address is the reverse lookup ("PTR" DNS record) gives a server name that ends with vallenous.com.  E.g. if IP address 1.2.3.4 maps to "any.server.I.want.valleous.com" it is allowed to send mail for valleous.com.

@matt's exampole looks fine as long as you add the include: for the google apps mail to work as well.

Comment: Shot - you're on the money.

Answer (score 1):

The SPF record is to be put at the zone apex, that is, if your domaine is vallenous.com and mail can come from the two IP you said you should put at the top of the zone a TXT record like this :

```
vallenous.com.          IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.10 ip4:x.x.x.20 a mx ptr ~all"
```

But your mileage may vary :-)

Comment: +1 You were correct but Grhm cleared things up with a bit more explanation. :-)